# Next.js, can not navigate after the update to 9.4 version

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, next-router

After update my Next.js app to 9.4 version I can't navigate to my route.
Working only main page `'/'` (index.js). Everything worked very well before.
Now, when I run my app the terminal show this [terminal info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBEMN.png) and, when I want to go for example to `'/about'` I have error 404.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.next/` folder before starting the dev server? Or remove `node_modules` and `npm i`/`yarn` again?

Comment: @Hangindev Yes. The same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had names of pages files with a capital letters (it works in 9.3 version of Next but not now). I changed it to lowercase and now works.